# Do we need multiple-entry Schengen visas?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

We, a US citizen and a Mexican citizen, will be traveling through the EU: Spain and Italy, and from there getting a 12-day tour through Croatia, Slovenia and Montenegro, for a total of 22 days.

We do not need a visa to any of these countries, but I am confused since Croatia is not part of the Schengen Zone.

Do I need a multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a visa for the Schengen zone, you do not need a visa for the Schengen zone, not even for multiple entries.

You will have to hold to the 90 out of 180 days rule but until you have been in the Schengen zone for 90 days in the last 180, you can come back in.